# Setting up the path in view in drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7, filtering

I have a taxonomy menu inside a mega menu in drupal7. I have created a  view for a primary link let say technology.

the url alias which i setted  for the technology menu is  http://localhost/drupal/technology
the technology have a secondary menu as  security which has url alias as http://localhost/drupal/technology/security and security contains the sub menu as car with url alias as http://localhost/drupal/technology/security/car .

I want a view to display in way that the technology page should contain all the article of securtiy and as well as car.

same way the security has to contain the article related to security as well as car.

The view which i created  looks like as follows.

[image]

Can any one help me how to set the path  for technology and for it sub menus .. I do no  whether the CONTEXTUAL FILTERS i setted is correct  or not. I i go to technology page i am not able to see the view which i created is getting affected.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the path to Drupal core's default for taxonomies `taxonomy/term/%`

The problem is that your view will replace all terms pages without being restricted to a given Vocabulary. If you need different Views for different Vocabularies you will have to take a look at [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) or [Taxonomy Views Switcher](http://drupal.org/sandbox/simg/1106944)